# Adding a row to the top of a tableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift2, xcode7

i am trying to add a row in an tableView on the top `let indexPath : [NSIndexPath] = [NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)]`
`parentTableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths(indexPath, withRowAnimation: .Fade)` but it is adding it to the bottom of tableView

This is my code :-

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController , UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource,transferDelegate , UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate{

var xibName : String = "HomepageFeedCellHeader"


var lords : [String] = ["name1","name2","name3"]

var queens : [String] = ["--","q1","q2"]

var desc : [String] = ["alpha","beta","gamma"]

var  menProfilePictures : [UIImage] = [UIImage(named: "DaarioNaharis")!,UIImage(named: "JaimeLannister")!,UIImage(named: "LordVarys")!]

@IBOutlet weak var postButton: UIButton!

@IBOutlet weak var parentTableView: UITableView!

@IBOutlet weak var pickImages: UIButton!

var a : ParentTableViewCell = ParentTableViewCell()

@IBOutlet weak var postTextView: UITextView!





override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()



    parentTableView.delegate = self
    parentTableView.dataSource = self


}




func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}




func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return desc.count
}



func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = parentTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ParentCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ParentTableViewCell


    cell.transferingDelegate = self


    cell.feedPostUsername.text = lords[indexPath.row]
    cell.feedPostUserDetails.text = queens[indexPath.row]
    cell.feedPostDescription.text = desc[indexPath.row]
    cell.feedUserProfilePictures.image = menProfilePictures[indexPath.row]
    cell.selectionStyle = .None


    return cell


}

func transfer(itemNo : Int) {

    print("call recieved in viewController from item \(itemNo)")

    let imagePopOverScene = self.navigationController?.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ImagePopOverViewControllerVC_ID") as? ImagePopOverViewController

    print("itemNo in viewControlle \(itemNo)")
    if itemNo < 3{

        imagePopOverScene?.setImage = menProfilePictures[itemNo]

    }else{

        imagePopOverScene?.setImage = UIImage(named: "defaultProfilePic")

    }

    imagePopOverScene?.transitioningDelegate = self

    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(imagePopOverScene!, animated: true)

}

@IBAction func postBtnAction(sender: UIButton) {

    print("post btn action recieved")
    tableViewConfiguration()

}

func tableViewConfiguration(){



    parentTableView.beginUpdates()

    desc.append(postTextView.text!)
    menProfilePictures.append(UIImage(named: "defaultProfilePic")!)
    queens.append("--")
    lords.append("Anonymous")

    let indexPath : [NSIndexPath] = [NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)]
    print(indexPath)
    parentTableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths(indexPath, withRowAnimation: .Fade)

    tableView(parentTableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath[0])

    parentTableView.endUpdates()
    parentTableView.reloadData()

    parentTableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(indexPath[0], atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.Top, animated: true)


}


@IBAction func pickImagesAction(sender: UIButton) {





}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, never call `reloadData` after calling `insertRowsAtIndexPaths` because `insertRowsAtIndexPaths` rearranges the table view implicitly.

But just this circumstance obscures the actual issue.

You're appending the new item(s) to the data source array(s) – by the way, why don't you use a custom struct instead of the three (**edit**: there are even four!) arrays – so they are *physically* at the end.

`insertRowsAtIndexPaths` inserts the item correctly at index 0 but the subsequent reloading of the table view moves the item according to the data source array again to the end of the table.

**Solution**: `insert` the item(s) at index 0 of the data source array(s) rather than `append` them.

**Edit**

A suggestion to use a custom struct

- Declare that outside your view controller

  ```
  struct Avatar {

    let lord : String
    let queen : String
    let desc : String
    let profileImage : UIImage?

    init(lord: String, queen: String, desc: String, imageName: String) {
      self.lord = lord
      self.queen = queen
      self.desc = desc
      self.profileImage = UIImage(named: imageName)
    }
  }
  ```
- In `ViewController` declare **one** data source array

  ```
  var avatars = [Avatar]()
  ```
- In `viewDidLoad` populate the data source array

  ```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      parentTableView.delegate = self
      parentTableView.dataSource = self

      avatars = [Avatar(lord: "name1", queen: "--", desc: "alpha", imageName: "DaarioNaharis"),
                 Avatar(lord: "name2", queen: "q1", desc: "beta", imageName: "JaimeLannister"),
                 Avatar(lord: "name3", queen: "q2", desc: "gamma", imageName: "LordVarys")]
      parentTableView.reloadData()
   }
  ```
- In `numberOfRowsInSection` return `avatars.count`
- In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` assign the properties

  ```
  let avatar = avatars[indexPath.row]
  cell.feedPostUsername.text = avatar.lord
  cell.feedPostUserDetails.text = avatar.queen
  cell.feedPostDescription.text = avatar.desc
  cell.feedUserProfilePictures.image = avatar.profileImage
  ```
- Replace `tableViewConfiguration` with

  ```
  func tableViewConfiguration(){
      let newAvatar = Avatar(lord: "Anonymous", queen: "--", desc: postTextView.text!, imageName: "defaultProfilePic"
      avatars.insert(newAvatar, atIndex: 0)
      let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)
      print(indexPath)
      parentTableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
      parentTableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, atScrollPosition: .Top, animated: true)
  }
  ```

Comment: Hey @vadian i am new to this , didn't really get it!.. also can you refer me to a documentation to clear my basics !

Comment: It's required to keep the model (data source array) and the view (table view) in sync that means you have to insert a new item in the data source array exactly at the same index as you expect it to appear in the table view.  Then  omit the `reloadData()` line and you are done.

Comment: Yea that what i don't know, how would you do that in code?...am a newbie..